# call for nested json objects, in ios

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I'm working on a ios project. I used AFNetworking to call json.
I just want to call for an specific json object. that meant for an specific nested json object.please help me to do that. as an example this is my json feed. In here I want to call for only first url inside thumbnail.

```
    {     status:"ok",
      count:50,
      count_total:44444,
      pates:333,
    - posts:[
        - {
            id:3333,
            type:"post",
            - thumbnail_images :{
                - full : {
                    url:"",
                    width:666
                },
                -thumbnail:{
                    url:"",
                    width:333

                    },
                - large:{
                    url:"",
                    width:777
                }
            }
        },
        - {
            id:3334,
            type:"post",
            - thumbnail_images :{
                - full : {
                    url:"",
                    width:6644
                },
                -thumbnail:{
                    url:"",
                    width:3345

                    },
                - large:{
                    url:"",
                    width:7778
                }
            }
        },
        - {
            id:333344,
            type:"post",
            - thumbnail_images :{
                - full : {
                    url:"",
                    width:6665
                },
                -thumbnail:{
                    url:"",
                    width:3336

                    },
                - large:{
                    url:"",
                    width:7770
                }
            }
        },

    ]

}
```

and also this is my objective-C method.

```
- (void)loadImagesToCategoryone
{
    imagespost = nil;
    NSString *urlOne = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some url"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *managerone = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [managerone GET:urlOne parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        imagesposts = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        NSArray *resultone = [imagesposts objectForKey:@"posts"];
        imagespost = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *imageone in resultone)
        {

                Categories *categoryone = [Categories new];
            NSArray *firstArray = [imageone objectForKey:@"thumbnail_images"];
            NSLog(@"%@",firstArray[0]);
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note that the `thumbnail_images` is a Dictionary not an Array.

```
NSArray *resultone = [imagesposts objectForKey:@"posts"];
if ([resultone count]) {
    //If need thumbnail of first post only then
    NSDictionary *firstPost = resultone[0];
    Categories *categoryone = [Categories new];
    NSDictionary *imageDetails = [imageone objectForKey:@"thumbnail_images"];
    NSDictionary *thumbnailImage = [imageDetails objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    NSString *urlString = [thumbnailImage objectForKey:@"url"];
        //Assume thumbnail image is required
        NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
}
```

Comment: thanx, but in here I want to call only for the first url of the first thumbnail.please help me with this @AKhilrajtr

Comment: from the json data, there is 3 types of image url's inside `thumbnail_images` and i think it with different sizes. You can use the above solution to use `thumbnail` type image from the json. If you need `full` or `large` just change the key `thumbnail` in `[imageDetails objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]`.

Comment: do you need to use thumbnail of first post? is that the requirement?

Comment: @anuk updated the answer to get thumbnail image url of first post only.

Comment: I'm checking on it, thanx again.

Comment: hey np.. actually i was bit confused by the question. thats why asked :)